# How to add three colors to horizontal bars with condition of factor loading more than 0.5

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

Here is my data

```
Parameters  RC1 RC2 RC3
NSC.Glucose 0.22    0.97    0.06
NSC.Fructose    0.38    0.57    0.1
NSC.Sucrose 0.13    0.63    0.06
NSC.Starch  0.23    0.72    0.06
Enzyme.INV  0.22    0.97    0.06
Enzyme.SPS  0.62    0.64    0.16
Enzyme.PGM  0.74    0.52    0.43
Enzyme.PFP  0.11    0.97    -0.02
Enzyme.AGP  -0.06   0.91    0.2
Enzyme.PGI  0.65    0.73    -0.2
Photosynthesis.Pn   0.12    0.82    0.15
Photosynthesis.Gm   0.02    0.38    0.01
Photosynthesis.Jmax 0.12    0.82    0.15
photosynthesis.Vcmax    0.12    0.82    0.15
gene.FBA    0.26    0.69    -0.03
gene.FBP    0.36    0.69    -0.02
gene.BFII   0.18    -0.78   -0.18
gene.CAB    0.23    0.73    0.05
gene.RuBisCo    0.31    0.75    -0.06
gene.RCA    0.49    0.28    0.07
gene.RPI    0.48    0.26    0.1
gene.PAL    0.43    -0.1    -0.14
gene.PSII   0.28    0.74    0.09
gene.STP    0.64    -0.41   -0.02
```

I want to prepare  horizontal bar plot with ggplot2
I want to have a figure like this (below image):
[image: RF loading as horizontal barplot]

I wrote this, need some help

```
library(ggplot2)
rf1<-read.table("I:/Sayantan/SayantanPhotosynthesis/Exceldata/RF.txt",header=T,sep="\t")
g<-ggplot(data = rf1, aes(y =RC1, x = Parameters, fill = RC1 < 0)) +geom_col() +coord_flip()
print (g)
```

Comment: Please describe in more detail what your question is.

Comment: @user2042106 I have added a solution. In order to let other folks help you better, [refer this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for your future posts.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to *conditionally* pick color to *fill* the bars:

```
df$fill <- ifelse(abs(df$RC1) > 0.5, "black", "white")          # conditional fill

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x= Parameters, y = RC1)) + geom_col(aes(fill = I(fill)), colour = "black") + 
     coord_flip() + theme_bw(base_size=10) + 
          geom_hline(yintercept = 0.5, color = 'black', linetype = "dotted")    
          # add another geom_hline if you need for - 0.5
```

[image: Factor loadings]

***data:***

```
df <- read.table(text = "Parameters  RC1 RC2 RC3
NSC.Glucose 0.22    0.97    0.06
NSC.Fructose    0.38    0.57    0.1
NSC.Sucrose 0.13    0.63    0.06
NSC.Starch  0.23    0.72    0.06
Enzyme.INV  0.22    0.97    0.06
Enzyme.SPS  0.62    0.64    0.16
Enzyme.PGM  0.74    0.52    0.43
Enzyme.PFP  0.11    0.97    -0.02
Enzyme.AGP  -0.06   0.91    0.2
Enzyme.PGI  0.65    0.73    -0.2
Photosynthesis.Pn   0.12    0.82    0.15
Photosynthesis.Gm   0.02    0.38    0.01
Photosynthesis.Jmax 0.12    0.82    0.15
photosynthesis.Vcmax    0.12    0.82    0.15
gene.FBA    0.26    0.69    -0.03
gene.FBP    0.36    0.69    -0.02
gene.BFII   0.18    -0.78   -0.18
gene.CAB    0.23    0.73    0.05
gene.RuBisCo    0.31    0.75    -0.06
gene.RCA    0.49    0.28    0.07
gene.RPI    0.48    0.26    0.1
gene.PAL    0.43    -0.1    -0.14
gene.PSII   0.28    0.74    0.09
gene.STP    0.64    -0.41   -0.02", header = TRUE , colClasses = c("character", rep("numeric", 3)))
```

Comment: Thank you for so much! It really worked. I am just beginner in ggplot 2 and R.

Comment: your welcome. upvote or accept if the solution worked for you, this lets other having similar queries get a better idea.